# Unable to load font from ttf file in lottie animation

Tags: android, json, animation, fonts, lottie

I am using this Lottie animation in android https://lottiefiles.com/70883-animation-fade-in-fade-out i have placed arial.ttf file in my assets/fonts folder with out it I was getting crash (not found file) but I think it is not reading it now...

Image link
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/103182879/162171733-da3d186b-cb7b-4f21-acdb-96237b65cedc.PNG
I have also try using programmatically but it also not working

Image link
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/103182879/162172016-c21527a7-8169-4a67-918e-a24de70bb89e.PNG
it not throwing any exception or error no crash nothing just not playing animation of text

Answer (score 0):

change name of font file from arial -> Arial. Always check the spelling from lottie json file. you can search for fFamily.